# window.crypto.subtle.encrypt returns undefined

Tags: javascript, cryptography, cryptoapi

I am trying to encrypt a text using the Web Crypto API. The following is my code:

```
const generatedIv = generateIv();
let generatedKey;
generateKey()
  .then(key => {
    generatedKey = key;
    encryptData(encodeText(JSON.stringify(data)), generatedKey, generatedIv);
  }).then(encrypted => {
    console.log(encrypted) // Always returns undefined?
  }).catch(
    err => console.error(err)
  );

function encodeText(data) {
  if ('TextEncoder' in window) {
    return new TextEncoder('utf-8').encode(data);
  }
  return undefined;
}

function generateIv() {
  return window.crypto.getRandomValues(new Uint8Array(12));
}

function generateKey() {
  return window.crypto.subtle.generateKey({
    name: 'AES-GCM',
    length: 256
  }, true, [
    'encrypt',
    'decrypt'
  ]);
}

function encryptData(data, key, iv) {
  return window.crypto.subtle.encrypt({
    name: 'AES-GCM',
    iv: iv,
    tagLength: 128
  }, key, data);
}
```

For some reason, the `console.log` statement always prints out `undefined`. I've tried looking on the web for possible solutions, but I wasn't able to find any.

Is there something that I am doing wrong here? Thanks in advance! :)

Comment: you're not returning anything in `.then(key => {` so of course the next then gets undefined as an argument

Comment: @JaromandaX `generateKey()` returns a promise, which will return the key value, hence `key` will not be undefined. I tested it with `console.log`.

Comment: yes - good ... but that callback to .then doesn't ...  added the answer with that `return` in place anyway - try it, then you'll see that for a function to return something - in this case the function called by `.then` - you actually have to return something

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
const generatedIv = generateIv();
let generatedKey;
generateKey()
  .then(key => {
    generatedKey = key;
    // you need to return something if you want the next .then to get anything
    return encryptData(encodeText("Hello World"), generatedKey, generatedIv);
  }).then(encrypted => {
    console.log("encrypted is an ArrayBuffer:", encrypted instanceof ArrayBuffer)
  }).catch(
    err => console.error(err)
  );

function encodeText(data) {
  if ('TextEncoder' in window) {
    return new TextEncoder('utf-8').encode(data);
  }
  return undefined;
}

function generateIv() {
  return window.crypto.getRandomValues(new Uint8Array(12));
}

function generateKey() {
  return window.crypto.subtle.generateKey({
    name: 'AES-GCM',
    length: 256
  }, true, [
    'encrypt',
    'decrypt'
  ]);
}

function encryptData(data, key, iv) {
  return window.crypto.subtle.encrypt({
    name: 'AES-GCM',
    iv: iv,
    tagLength: 128
  }, key, data);
}
```

Running the above, you should see `encrypted is an ArrayBuffer: true` - because that's what you'd expect the encrypted result is, an ArrayBuffer ... so, huzzah - a simple `return` was all that was required, to return a value (in this case the promise returned by `window.crypto.subtle.encrypt`) to the next `.then` ... otherwise known as promise chaining

Have a great day

Comment: maybe the `key => { ... }` tripped you up? it's a function, right, so you do need a `return` ... of course, the single statement version of arrow ... like `v => v+1` ... doesn't need a `return` - it is implied - so perhaps that was the source of confusion